# Is there a way to switch to write mode if i had opened a file in read only mode in vim?

Tags: vim

Sometimes i feel annoyed closing it from read only and opening it again in write mode to edit. If haven't opened a file with sudo permission and if incase i just want to switch that by some command within a vim. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command to save a file you edited in vim without the needed permissions:

```
:w !sudo tee %
```